# Find differences in two arrays and put differences in an a new array or variables

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have two arrays

```
 Array ( [0] => db [1] => es [2] => fs [3] => rp [4] => ti [5] => wb )////array $a
 Array ( [0] => es [1] => db [2] => fs ) ///array $b
```

I need to compare array `$b` to `$a` and put the ones that are missing in `$b` in a new array `$c`

```
 $c=array();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$c = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$a =  array ( [0] => db [1] => es [2] => fs [3] => rp [4] => ti [5] => wb );
$b =  array ( [0] => es [1] => db [2] => fs ) ///array $b
$c = array_dif ( $a , $b );
```

Comment: Sorry, @John_Conde responded way earlier, if you want to give the marks, provide it to him. Same solution though.